# -> operator with a reference variable? (C++)

Tags: c++

Is there any situation where you use -> operator with a reference variable/ object?

```
typedef ABC::Derived<Tmplt> THandle;
THandle m_oNew;    
m_oNew->m_u16GetState();    // This is the function call. Here "->" is used.
```

This is the class "Derived" and the function definition:

```
template<class T>
class Derived;

class AnotherClass
{
    friend class Derived;

    inline AnimState m_u16GetState () const
    {
        return m_u16State;
    }
};
```

Comment: With a reference to a pointer or a type that overloads `operator->`.

Comment: `operator->` is almost definitely overloaded for this to make sense.

Comment: I am sorry...i just checked again...the class is defined some place else..the operator "->" is overloaded...
sorry for the confusion...
and thank you for the prompt replies... :)

Comment: -1: There is no logic in what you are writing.

Answer (score 4):

if X->Y is used,
then X must either,
a) be a pointer variable or, 
b) '->' operator must be overloaded for the type of X